# Deep Learning Book: What's the meaning of Pa in this section?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I'm reading [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org) and puzzled by this "undefined identifier" (the Pa in the image, line 4). It appears at Page 208. Can you tell me just what Pa() means? Just a tip so that I can refer to Google. Thanks a lot!

[Link to origin image | I'm not allowed to post image directly](https://tdl.recolic.net/tmp/snap-0710-184503.png)

Comment: Pa = means Parents indicating that it is dependent from the previous nodes state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "Parents". The feed forward computation needs the values of the previous nodes to proceed.